# Set duplicated buttons to register click events jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is duplicated when a button inside that div is clicked. Each duplicated div also contains a button that should duplicate the div. Right now, only the original div "duplicate" button works. I need each button to duplicate the div which contains the button. Here is the my jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('.duplicate-button').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).closest('.desking-finance').clone().appendTo('.extra-finance-lease');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `.clone(true)` to clone data and events as well

Comment: You could also use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and attach the handler to a common parent element that exists on initial page load. If you post your markup, someone can provide a specific example.

Comment: Adeneo, thanks that got it. If you want leave a answer I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the execution of this function. It only targets existing elements and not potentially new elements that may be created.

In order to have this function execute on click for every (new or old) div, use **live** to target them. Here is the refactored code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.duplicate-button', function() {
        $(this).closest('.desking-finance').clone().appendTo('.extra-finance-lease');
    });
});
```

I used **document** to bind the click handler but try and use a closer parent element relative to the duplicate-buttons. Perhaps some container div.

There was no need for **$.each** since *$(this)* will target the targeted element that triggered the event.

Comment: `.live()` was [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: thank you for the tip! We should be using .on instead